# Use selenium WebDriver to select radio button from text

Tags: html, selenium, radio-button, webdriver

We've got some poorly written radio buttons on a legacy page as follows:

```
<input id="button1" name="button" value="32" onchange="assignProduct(this.value);" type="radio"></input>
RADIO TEXT 1
<input id="button2" name="button" value="33" onchange="assignProduct(this.value);" type="radio"></input>
RADIO TEXT 2
```

for information, this displays the same as would:

```
<input id="button" name="button" value="32" onchange="assignProduct(this.value);" type="radio">RADIO TEXT 1</input>
<input id="button" name="button" value="33" onchange="assignProduct(this.value);" type="radio">RADIO TEXT 2</input>
```

The latter code is more correct and allows selection of input button by text "RADIO TEXT 2" by:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[contains(@text, 'RADIO TEXT 2')])")).click();
```

What code can I use to find the radio button in the first code sample, which is what I actually have to deal with?

The text is no longer contained within the  element so .xpath() doesn't match it.

I need to find the text, then click the input immediately prior? Can I do this without consuming and traversing the entire page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [XPath axes](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp). In this particular case `following-sibling`. I've designed a locator to demonstrate it on this page. Look at the @bansalshah's answer. Lets select `<p>` where the following text contains `for eg`. It works, Ive checked this :)

`.//*[@id='answer-25883774']//div[@class='post-text']/p[./following-sibling::*[contains(., 'for eg')]]`

So, in your case, to select the input for RADIO TEXT 2 this should be something like

`.//input[@type='radio'][./following-sibling::*[contains(., 'RADIO TEXT 2')]]`

Answer (score 1):

For the first example, you can access buttons by there `ID`:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button1")).click(); //first button
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.id("button2")).click(); //second button
```

If the Id is not enough, you can, using `xpath`, access to them via `id` and `value`:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='button1'][@value='32']")).click(); //first button
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='button2'][@value='33']")).click(); //first button
```

Comment: @CharlieS asks if he's able to make an XPath locator according to following text, not id or something else

Comment: as @AlexanderPetrovich comments, I don't necessarily know the id/value.  In many html generating engines these might change with each build, but the text the end user will see is unlikely to change as often.

Answer (score 0):

From the code which i can see you can map the values with text

for eg value=32 for radio text 1
and get the value from the xpath

if value =32 then select the radio button

Hope this helps

Comment: this does not answer the question. i don't know the value i want to find, i only know the text following. i could also select by id if i knew it.